# numpy.random to select a value from a given list that is itself selected at from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am a bit stuck on something that I feel silly for being stuck on so any advise from a fresh pair of eyes will be helpful.

I have an array containing 12 age groups, most age groups contain 4 ages.

```
a1 = ([15,16,17,18,19])
a2=([20,21,22,23,24])
a3=([25,26,27,28,29])
a4=([30,31,32,33,34])
a5=([35,36,37,38,39])
a6=([40,41,42,43,44])
a7=([45,46,47,48,49])
a8=([50,51,52,53,54])
a9=([55,56,57,58,59])
a10=([60,61,62,63,64])
a11=([65,66,67,68,69])
a12=([70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80])
age=([a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12])
```

The probability that any of the age groups will be selected is:

```
age_prob=[0.1, 0.125, .145,.13,.115,.1,.085,.075,.02,.06,.035,.01]
```

Once an age group is selected, I want to extract a single age from that group with equal probability. This age is then added to column until it contains 100 ages. This will generate an age for me:

```
age_group=np.random.choice(age, p=age_prob)
Age=np.random.choice(age_group)
Age
```

But if I try to create 100 ages I get an array of 100 age groups
`

```
 age_group=np.random.choice(age, p=age_prob)
    Age=np.random.choice(age_group,100)
    Age
```

I tried this approach for a while:

```
age_indices = np.random.choice(len(age), 100, replace=True, p=age_prob)
Age=[age[i] for i in age_indices]
Age1=np.random.choice(Age,100)
```

But got this out

```
array([list([20, 21, 22, 23, 24]), list([45, 46, 47, 48, 49]),
   list([40, 41, 42, 43, 44]), list([35, 36, 37, 38, 39]),
   list([15, 16, 17, 18, 19]), list([25, 26, 27, 28, 29]),
   list([40, 41, 42, 43, 44]), list([60, 61, 62, 63, 64]),
   list([45, 46, 47, 48, 49]), list([30, 31, 32, 33, 34]),.....
```

Hope I clear,and any advise welcome, Thanks.

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
l = []

for i in np.random.choice(age, p=age_prob, size=100):
    l.append(np.random.choice(i))
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[21, 15, 35, 34, 53, 20, 48, 27, 29, 37, 56, 55, 24, 26, 52, 59, 54, 48, 29, 39, 35, 29, 54, 62, 79, 67, 46, 49, 50, 28, 69, 28, 24, 34, 24, 48, 29, 36, 34, 48, 21, 49, 55, 26, 17, 31, 22, 22, 20, 17, 62, 51, 29, 53, 20, 18, 32, 52, 23, 42, 64, 32, 60, 39, 34, 46, 48, 21, 50, 53, 34, 23, 31, 34, 77, 37, 20, 23, 23, 25, 79, 22, 23, 20, 38, 24, 54, 39, 34, 31, 32, 44, 24, 52, 44, 50, 46, 25, 28, 15]
```

Comment: Seems to be doing the what I need. Appreciate it.